# How to scale in order for a graphic to keep it's limits?

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

[image: bad representation of input]
[image: good representation of input]

Hello,

I need help with something.

I have to draw a graphic(more exactly a function that counts the number of prime numbers up to a given number: f(givenNumber)=number of prime numbers<=givenNumber,n>0).

In order to do that I used a Rectangle(this is were the graphic gets drawn),Graphics,Pen and Size(for client space).

My BIG question is as following:

-if I input 10-100, the graphic is correctly drawn into the rectangle without getting out.
Nevertheless if I input 1000, the graphic gets out of the rectangle "infinitely".

**How do I scale,what to use, so that no matter how many points would I have, the graphic keeps it's limits?**
If it helps, the code would be:

```
// get the graphics object and create our pen for drawing.
object[] args;
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
// figure out the client space
Size sz = this.ClientSize;
// Determine the rectangle that we will use to draw
int offsetHeight = this.textBox1Limita.Location.Y + this.textBox1Limita.Height + 20;
int offsetWidth = 40;
int maxWidth = sz.Width - offsetWidth * 2;
int maxHeight = sz.Height - offsetHeight * 2;
Rectangle drawingSpace = new Rectangle(offsetWidth, offsetHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight);
// Draw the begining rectangle
g.DrawRectangle(pen, offsetWidth, offsetHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight);
// at this point, only continue if the user pressed enter in one of the two input boxes.
if (!ValuesEntered) return;
try
{
   args = new object[1];
   args[0] = int.Parse(this.textBox1Limita.Text);
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // We reached here, the user input some bogus values into the box.
   // Just return so we dont do anything with those values.
   return;
}

int lim=(int)mi.Invoke(o, args);
int step =5;
int k = 1;

g.DrawLine(pen, drawingSpace.X + 1 * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - 1 * step, drawingSpace.X + 2 * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - 1 * step);

for (int j = 0; j <lim; j++)
{
   if (j == lim-1)
   {
      g.DrawLine(pen, drawingSpace.X + vectorPrime[j] * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - k * step, drawingSpace.X + (int)args[0] * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - k * step);
   }
   else
  {
      g.DrawLine(pen, drawingSpace.X + vectorPrime[j] * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - k * step, drawingSpace.X + (vectorPrime[j + 1]-1) * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - k * step);

      g.DrawLine(pen, drawingSpace.X + (vectorPrime[j + 1]-1) * step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - k * step, drawingSpace.X + vectorPrime[j+1]*step, offsetWidth + maxHeight - (k+1)*step);
      k++;
  }
}
```

Oh, and something else, I found something with Graphics.FillEllipse...would that be a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the platform your aiming for? can you post some screenshots?

Comment: You can either pre-calculate how many values you'll have and thereby deduce the dimensions and calculate a scale for your items and then redraw, or look into a scalable solution such as SVG.  If you really need infinite scalability, SVG sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I added those screenshots.. What is SVG? :-S

Comment: Since you already know C#, look into WPF for making charts that can stretch. I've done it, and it wasn't too difficult, though I don't recall enough to post a proper answer. This is not to say you can't achieve the same using GDI+ (which'll probably be faster), but WPF is nice. There's a steep learning curve for WPF, though.